# Is it worth it to transition into more open lines when one is used to closed, positional games?

Tags: opening

I've played the French and Queen's Gambit, which tend to lead to more closed, positional play.  I've played these openings consistently for roughly 25+ years now, with no set opening before then really.  I did try to learn both the Center counter, or Scandinavian, and the Danish early but eventually gave up and played random moves (I was quite young).  After that it was Petrov for a year, then on to closed games.  I'm currently 38 and have been at closed positions now for 25+ years.  By consistent I mean every single game I've played since then.  If it is relevant my USCF is around 1500, with a peak of 1620.

Comment: It's a tradeoff between the experience you gain playing open games which will improve your play in closed positions which blow up and the lack of experience of open games which will impede your play in open games.

Comment: I don't know that's its really that cut and dry, particularly since my choice was really between no opening at all (as I said, I was quite young and rebelled against the idea of a set opening) and an opening.  

My objective as a player has always been to just get out of the opening and win decisively in the middle.  Closed openings get into the middle game quickly, with less memorization (not saying there aren't complications).  However, if I were to actually start memorizing lines, and put more time into the opening, I feel I'd improve my play immensely.

Comment: Well that's a different question and if you want to memorise lines then do that.

Comment: ^I didn't ask a question in the previous comment.

Comment: Don't split hairs. You brought up a different issue, the question of memorising lines. I gave you my response. Do whatever you want.

Comment: I was just trying to avoid us talking past one another, as internet chat can be, well, misinterpreted from time to time.  They aren't unrelated, as my very reasons for choosing an opening was to not have to memorize.  If I memorized it might improve play.  However, much of the formulation of player strength is done early in age, I've found.  I suppose it might be a case of whether I could actually go back after all these years and learn.  I suspect even though I can look back in retrospect and see why I never advanced, my options are now limited rating wise.

Comment: That isn't to say that I don't know the basics,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a strong expert:

Just because I find open games to be more fun, I would suggest playing more open games.  Also a variety of openings will expand your knowledge.  (Looking at your tournament history, you may already have enough knowledge.)  Just like you don't quit smoking in one day, don't switch to overly aggressive opening.  Try the Scotch, Vienna, or Giuoco Piano.  These openings requires the learning of more opening traps, but they should improve your quality of play.

Assuming that you have the time to invest in studying an opening, learn the common positions and plans.  If after trying this style you feel uncomfortable, go back to playing the closed/positional games.  If the game is not fun, it is not worth playing.

When I reached expert level, I switched to a more positional game because I thought this is what was supposed to happen.  I lost many games because I hid my talent.

Some GM said that he switched to d4 because he got lazy as he got old.  Anna Zatonskih said that with d4, White can make more mistakes before losing the game.  You could be hanging on to the safety of known avenues.

Answer (score 4):

My advice is to change openings only if you don't enjoy them and to practice tactics for when a game opens up. This is because:

1. The aim of the opening is to reach a playable middlegame. You reach a playable middlegame in any reputable opening, whether it is the wide open King's Gambit or the closed Advanced French
2. If you enjoy the openings you play, stick with them. Chess is a game afterall, and if you are having fun with the openings you use, then that's great!
3. Most games can be opened up if the opponent wants to do badly enough, so practice tactics to be prepared for open games. Think of the French Exchange Variation for example

Comment: My responses to your list is given:  1) Although I agree with you ultimately about the goal of the opening, there is more memorization required for certain openings to achieve this.  For example, there are certain lines of the Sicilian that can go very long and deep, move wise.  I had a tendency to avoid those.  

2) Agreed!

3) While positions can be opened at a cost, I was quite good at making opponents either pay too much to open the position up, or, memorizing as few lines as necessary to get into the middle game with, at most, a slight disadvantage.

Comment: Now, as it currently stands, I'm thinking I could avoid the slight disadvantage that cost me MANY games.  I can remember many of my games where a pawn advantage was key one way or another to victory.  How much of a rating boost I would achieve from trying to change openings is unknown, however, I really don't think spending more time on tactics is the way to go to get the fastest improvement.

Comment: @PaulBurchett: I can't answer what the best way for you to improve your game is in the comments I'm afraid. If you like, feel free to ask a new question, or to look at existing questions tagged as 'learning'

Comment: My case is an odd one.  Don't take too much offense that you can't give advice, as I think it took much introspection to reach certain conclusions, I feel.  If anything maybe this thread is useful in showing that even the rule "tactics first" can have exceptions!

Comment: No problem, and no offence taken @PaulBurchett.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Unboudtedly, playing subpar when the game opens up is a crutch. Moreover, advantages in some closed positions come in the form of opening up the position at the right moment. In some openings, you should be on the look-out for such opportunities (and aware of similar opportunities for your opponent).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be playing open games, tactical chess, not positional chess and closed/semi-closed positions. Positional chess is inherently more difficult than open, tactical games. It's sounds to me you suffer from the classic idea that "closed" positions somehow protect you from tactics. If you are "afraid" of a tactical fight, become better at tactics! That is a learnable skill. Positional play is way more difficult and requires a deeper understanding to become a "positional" player, which maybe you think you are, or more accurately, you think that is what you *want* to become. But, most games die by tactics. I've never lost a game to a player who outplayed me positionally - in the end, tactics decides it almost all the time. Of course, be aware of positional motifs in a tabiya, but that is experience talking there.

You should go out swinging as a C-player and trial by fire instead of ducking for cover at every opportunity. "Closed" positions for 38+ years as a C-Player should tell you something. It ain't workin'.

You're chasing the wrong kite. You need to be at least 2100+ to even think about defining your "style" in that respect.

I would go for the most violent openings you can find - Scotch, Giuoco Piano, Kings Gambit - at Class C you don't worry about theory in the least. Just know enough to get into the middlegames and take the gloves off and punch each other in the face. Last man standing.

FYI: USCF 1871

Comment: I'll respectfully disagree.  Class C says so little in comparison to my 6 mathematics papers and my disposition as a kid!  Two with referees.  Conjectures 1 and 2 are out there.  Conjecture 3 on the way!  No way I'm wrong on any of them!

Comment: To add, at Cat C, there are no exceptions to what you should be studying. It should be 1: Tactics; 2: Endgames; 3: your own losses; 4: Annotated Grandmaster Games.

Comment: For most Mark, you're right.

Comment: Some of the great classic masters of chess tried to define chess in mathematical "terms". Today, it is known as dogma. And I'm sure you're right in saying you can be brilliant in math and no-so-brilliant at chess.... skill in one does not translate to the other. Chess is not Math, and Math, not chess. Chess is much harder. Math is simply a lesson in practice mechanics.

Comment: So one of your contentions is that chess is harder than mathematics.  Mathematics is much more than practice mechanics.  This definition misses the creative aspects of mathematics.  I'll comment on the rest a bit later, not on my phone.

Comment: Using mathematics could lead to some great insight.  Why are you so biased against that? While the game is certainly complex from a human point of view, that doesn't mean we can't use mathematical language to explain many things.  It is better than oh so many dead chess cliches, many of which are gibberish!

Comment: If we are to advance at all in the study of combinatorial games then the method needs to be formalistic in nature!  Make clear claims!  I have!

Comment: Yawn. I guess my point is that if you practiced chess like you practiced Math (i.e., the right things), you'd not be here asking these questions. You would not be languishing in the 1500's, and you would find it unnecessary to take shots at old dead chess clichés that you might do well following on occasion. I'm sure if you posted a game or two they could be verbalized using steinitzian phrasing, Philodorianisms, and Morphy-ologies, to death I'm sure. But, I will defer to your academic accomplishments in Mathematics and assume you know better and leave it as "gibberish".

Comment: I'm here for love of the game, pure and simple.  At this point I have to ask, why are you here?  Not in the forum, as you have my respect for your play, but why such hostility?

Comment: No hostility here. you asked a question, you got answers, then proceeded to argue the points. So, why are YOU here? Sounds like you are not interested in the answers but in arguments - good answers you have gotten, no doubt, in more than one thread. I'll end with that. Good like on reaching back into the 1600's. I wish you well, and Good Chess.

Comment: Much hostility in the above.  I have upvoted elsewhere more than once.  I stated why I was here.  You haven't.  My last post addressing you, as I'm off to enjoy life.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is interesting but not to the point, if you allow me to say. You are speaking about openings and your problem is not about opening. When you say you have been playing closed openings for years, what do you really mean? Are you playing those out of interest or out of fear or prudence? I would advice you, given your rating, to restudy from the beginning the game of chess. Study all of its history with commented games and try to make progress tactically. Practise and practise again until you get a grip on tactics: this is the major step to mastering the basics of chess. You should be prudent: books for beginners and weaker players always insist on ideas, and they are right, but you should not forget that a minimal mastery of concrete tactical chess is unmistakenly necessary. There is no progress without this. Playing closed openings closes road for your progress. There are good books for you to study: just think of Yusupov's course in several volumes, for instance. You read the book with a board aside (computer also) and you think what you want to play and what could be annoying to you. Then when reaching your conclusion, you look up with computer assistance and finally you try to figure out why computer moves are better than yours. This is a very rude way to learn but you will make progress. You can keep on playing your openings, they are not bad, but play them with an open mind and try to master tactics. You rating will then go up. I know this is not comfortable, but there is no such thing as comfort when trying to progress. Maybe you will even lose elo points in the beginning, and so what, if you risk nothing you get nothing. Just try, it's a game, open and closed. Open games are more dangerous in the short term BUT you have to master them to understand what underlies closed positions when those get opened. Closing positions is not an aim in itself, it's just a means. Sorry for being so direct but i really want to help you ahead.
Greetings!

Comment: I understand the basics.  Pins, skewers, forks, combinations, etc.

As I've stated, I've played competitively for years, before leaving tournament play after college.  I still dabbled, just never spent the TIME to memorize lines, I just enjoyed playing.

Tell me, do YOU play out of fear?

Comment: When I say I understand the basics let me just say quickly that I played scholastically for 12 years, and won state trophies every year, save for one which I couldn't play in.

Comment: Btw, I defined exactly what I meant by playing closed openings!

Comment: Do you not agree that both 1.d4 for white (versus 1.e4) and the French are both closed?  Whereas the Scandinavian, Petrov, and Danish are more open?

Comment: I cannot help you more. You don't seem to accept what i say: if you have only a 1620 USCF rating, there is something wrong in your chess education. It is not a question of types of openings played, sorry to say. Free to you, of course, to not accept my advice. And whether your openings are more closed or not, i really don't know. Look at the recent French games at top level by Harikrishna. And yes, i am scared when playing, so should anyone be, except geniuses like Tal, and even him...The name is simply "prophylaxis". Sorry, if i have been rude, but i wanted to be honest and help you really.

Comment: Perhaps it was the education, but I don't think that's entirely the case.  To be fair to a man that coached teams to 3 National Scholastic titles in the US, maybe I was a kid being a kid!

Comment: Ok, sorry then. I do however not understand how you could "coach" teams with such a "limited" elo (no offence meant). Anyway, if you want an answer that goes the way you feel: yes, there are openings which are more open in nature. And once again, i didn't want to hurt you but i am a pretty strong player you know and i really want to help you transcend your playing level (even if you are underrated). Whether it is worth for you to transition to more open games, you already know my answer.

Comment: I never claimed I was the coach.  However, you're quite wrong even if I were the coach, as my old coach and chess legend Edward "Pete" Shaw only had a USCF of a little over 1600!  Don't believe me, go to the USCF website.  The dedicated man coached teams to National Championships!

Comment: Ok, then. Remain with your certitudes.

Comment: What certitudes, exactly?

Comment: It's a pity you take it so aggressively. This was not the intent on my part: i just wanted to help you honestly. Do you not want to climb the ladder till 1800 elo, for instance? It's really possible, i think. It's open to everybody.

Comment: To me 1800 would be achievable, but probably not worth my time given life and my early attitude towards the game. That isn't to say I couldn't add much to the game by coaching, and as a chess historian, for example.

Comment: Hi @PaulBurchett and John. My understanding of John's answer is that if a player wants to progress to a certain rating, then the specific opening is not as important as, say, studying tactics, principles and annotated games. Is that summary accurate John?

Comment: Yes, it is clearly summarized.

Comment: Bad_Bishop, I'd agree in most circumstances that tactics should studied first, however there are exceptions to any rule.

Comment: https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1298&dat=19840521&id=qfhNAAAAIBAJ&sjid=WIsDAAAAIBAJ&pg=3121,3343535&hl=en

Comment: http://www.uschess.org/component/option,com_wrapper/Itemid,181

Shaw, Edward  State:  VA

Just sayin'